# Scraping multiple Pages in a Loop gives Duplicated results in 3rd Level

Tags: python, scrapy

In my following HTML Templates:

---

**Level 1** (Template_1)

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="template_2.html">Template 2 (Level 2)</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Level 2** (Template_2)

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="template_3.html">Template 3 (Level 3)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="template_4.html">Template 4 (Level 3)</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Level 3** (Template_3 & Template_4)

```html
<h1>Template 3 Text</h1>
```

```html
<h1>Template 4 Text</h1>
```

---

What I'm trying to do is to enter **Level 1** `HTML` Page, Then pull the **Text** of each `a` element then enter it to pull each `h1` element **Text** using the following Spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class LESpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Loop Error'
    start_urls = ['template_1.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {
            'temp_text': None,
            'text': None
        }

        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(), callback=self.parse_lv2, dont_filter=True, meta={"data": data})

    def parse_lv2(self, response):
        for a in response.css('a'):
            data = response.meta.get('data')

            data['temp_text'] = a.css('a::text').extract_first()

            yield scrapy.Request(url=a.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(), callback=self.parse_lv3, dont_filter=True, meta={"data": data})


    def parse_lv3(self, response):
        data = response.meta.get('data')

        data['text'] = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()

        yield data
```

My problem is like the following, Firstly the Result I expect is this

```
[
  {"temp_text": "Template 3 (Level 3)", "text": 'Template 3 Text'},
  {"temp_text": "Template 4 (Level 3)", "text": 'Template 4 Text'}
]
```

But what I get is the following result:

```
[
  {"temp_text": "Template 4 (Level 3)", "text": "Template 3 Text"},
  {"temp_text": "Template 4 (Level 3)", "text": "Template 4 Text"}
]
```

Where I get `temp_text` duplicated of the last value of the `a` elements in **Level 2**

I thought the problem is where I placed my `yield data` so I put it under the **parse_lv2**'s `yield` like this

```
yield scrapy.Request(url=a.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(), callback=self.parse_lv3, dont_filter=True, meta={"data": data})

yield data
```

But didn't get the data from **parse_lv3**,

Tried to check which part is the problem So I removed the **parse_lv3** and the `yield scrapy.Request(url=a.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(), callback=self.parse_lv3, dont_filter=True, meta={"data": data})` from **parse_lv2**,

replacing it with `yield data`,

And the problem solved (wihtout **parse_lv3** data),

So I'm sure the problem is either in the Loop or the **parse_lv3** `yield`, But can't figure out How to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you only define `data` once in `parse` so every loops in `parse_lv2` will share the same dict `data` and every loop in `parse_lv3` will share `data` too, that's why at the end you have the result of the last loop of `parse_lv2`in `data['temp_text']`.

You'd better initialize `data` in the loop of `parse_lv2` like that

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.Request(url=response.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(), callback=self.parse_lv2, dont_filter=True)


def parse_lv2(self, response):
    for a in response.css('a'):
        data = dict()
        data['temp_text'] = a.css('a::text').extract_first()
        yield scrapy.Request(url=a.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(), callback=self.parse_lv3, dont_filter=True, meta={"data": data})
```

Comment: The problem that I pull some data in `parse` too, But didn't write them Since they didn't seem important, Will add a sample o fit in `parse` now

Comment: So you should probably make a copy of the dict in order not to have the same dict in every loop of `parse_lv2`, so you should try to replace `data = response.meta.get('data')` by `data = response.meta.get('data').copy()` in `parse_lv2`

Comment: @Yes, That solved if it is possible, May you explain to me how did a Copy change it?

Comment: Sure, the problem with dict is that we manipulate a pointer to the python object. So if you do `a=dict()` and then `b=a` `b` and `a` will use the same dict which means that if you modifiy `a` it will modifiy `b` too, that's why here you have a problem because when you did `data['temp_text'] = a.css('a::text').extract_first()` it modified all the dict gave to `parse_lv2` and `parse_lv3`. Whereas if you do `b=a.copy()` rather than `b=a`, python will create a new python object that is a copy of `a` and a new pointer to that object which will be linked with `b`so modifying `a` will not modifiy `b`